# Get all documents, and in case of equality (similarity) - later ones

Tags: mongodb

There is a parser for sports. It works in a circle. By some logic, sports events are added to the database. In each parsing cycle, a sports event can be added to the database, but it may not be added)

I need to get all sports events from the last two parsing cycles. But, if there is a sporting event in both cycles, then only from the last one. This is the problem. Sample documents:

```
 {
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "parseCount": 0
  },
  {
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "parseCount": 1
  },
  {
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "parseCount": 2
  },
  {
    "command1": "C",
    "command2": "D",
    "parseCount": 1
  },
  {
    "command1": "E",
    "command2": "F",
    "parseCount": 2
  },
```

As a result, I should get the last 3 documents from the list above. The document also has fields: match time and ObjectId

https://mongoplayground.net/p/-9gz4zOnudW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly you can first `$sort` and then get `$first` object into `$group` like this:

I've used `$first: $$ROOT` but you can use `$first: value` for each value from the object if you want.

This query:

- First sort by `parseCount` to get the higher value in first position.
- Then `$group` by two conditions, getting the first object (as is ordered is the higher one)
- And use `$project` to get output values you want.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "parseCount": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "command1": "$command1",
        "command2": "$command2"
      },
      "object": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": "$object._id",
      "command1": "$object.command1",
      "command2": "$object.command2",
      "parseCount": "$object.parseCount"
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5zBKH48zyXx)

Answer (score 1):

Query

- its like 2 queries but can become 1 with lookup
- facet could be used and do 2 groups but would be limited to max 16mb
  data in collection, the bellow solution hasn't this limitation
- finds the max parse for the collection using the lookup
  (mongodb auto-optimizes it, so the pipeline in lookup will run only 1 time
  not for each document of collection, at least this happened when i tested it in the past)
- we keep only the last 2 parses, for example if `max=3` we keep `parseCount=3` and `parseCount=2` , we also keep only parseCount>0, you had that filter on Playground, if you dont need it remove it.
- group by `command1,command2` and keep only the max `parseCount` you said that we keep only the latest if we have more than 1
- project to restore the document structure, `matchTime` and `_id` are kept also because you said you have those also

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L_FxitUC7O3)

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "maxParse": {
              "$max": "$parseCount"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "result"
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "maxParses": {
        "$let": {
          "vars": {
            "v0": {
              "$arrayElemAt": [
                "$result",
                0
              ]
            }
          },
          "in": "$$v0.maxParse"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": [
      "result"
    ]
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$and": [
          {
            "$gt": [
              "$parseCount",
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            "$gte": [
              "$parseCount",
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  "$maxParses",
                  1
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "command1": "$command1",
        "command2": "$command2"
      },
      "maxParseCount": {
        "$max": {
          "parseCount": "$parseCount",
          "matchTime": "$matchTime",
          "id": "$_id"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$_id",
          "$maxParseCount",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "command1": 1,
      "command2": 1,
      "parseCount": 1,
      "matchTime": 1,
      "_id": "$id"
    }
  }
])
```

To explain what query does based on your data

- will find maxParse=2 (lookup does this)
- first document will filtered out, because 2,1 parses are only kept
  and it has 0
- the rest one will be grouped by command1,command2
  "A","B" has 2 documents(`_id=2,_id=3`) but only `_id=3` will pass because it has the max parseCount

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 1,
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "parseCount": 0,
    "matchTime": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": 2,
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "parseCount": 1,
    "matchTime": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "parseCount": 2,
    "matchTime": 3
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "command1": "C",
    "command2": "D",
    "parseCount": 1,
    "matchTime": 4
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "command1": "E",
    "command2": "F",
    "parseCount": 2,
    "matchTime": 5
  }
]
```

Results

```js
[
  {
    "_id": 3,
    "command1": "A",
    "command2": "B",
    "matchTime": 3,
    "parseCount": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": 4,
    "command1": "C",
    "command2": "D",
    "matchTime": 4,
    "parseCount": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": 5,
    "command1": "E",
    "command2": "F",
    "matchTime": 5,
    "parseCount": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. The query works. But it looks very difficult compared to the other answer

Comment: you said you wanted only latest 2 cycles, see this latest_parse=10 , and parseCount=5 passes, when only 10,9 should pass. this query keeps only 9,10 [see this](mongoplayground.net/p/gGi9ZugsU3i )This is done by the first part of the query, the group is similar with JF answer but with max (sort is needed if we need more than 1) if we need only 1 max is faster but sort is fine also. If you dont need the latest 2 , use the part from the group and bellow or the sort solution

Comment: Yes you are right. But this is fix,  if the first stage is to add a query like `{ $match: {      parseCount: { $gte: 9  }    }  }`

Comment: this cant fix it, because we dont know the max parseCount before running the query.
If you want 1 query solution at least, with 2 queries solution, you can do it with that, but because auto optimized 1 query solution works ok, as far as i know , BUT if you know the max-parseCount before running the query, you can use after the group+ max or sort+group as JF solution both are fine

Comment: Yes, i know max `parseCount` .... but for this i make additional query ) . I have one document, like `stat`, which includes current `parseCount`

Comment: ok the above solution is like in 1 query both, i am not sure what happens in cuncurency, for example you do the first query and you get max parseCount=10, and before sending the second query it gets max parseCount=11(someone else change it), you will query based on old data. but i am not sure how this works in case of the lookup and 1 query.